# iPad safari html5 audio playback

Tags: ipad, html, audio, safari, nginx

I use HTML5 to play mp3 file on iPad.

I put two audio tags:

1. One use audio source from
   http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/_mp3/office_lobby.mp3
2. The other is from my local nginx server, the mp3 file is download
   from
   http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/_mp3/office_lobby.mp3

After I click play button on audio player controls, both of them can play. 
The remote one can playback; but mp3 from my local nginx can't playback, it always shows 'streaming...' even after the mp3 playing is done.

The HTML5 code is below:

```
<p>Remote</p>
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/_mp3/office_lobby.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
  Audio not support!
</audio>
<p>Local Nginx</p>
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="http://192.168.1.100/office_lobby.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
  Audio not support!
</audio>
```

I want to know why two audio controls behave diffrently.
Is it nginx configuration problem?

[image: Snapshot]

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Hi @CeaneLamerez, my question is how to configure my nginx server so that the HTML5 audio control use mp3 file from my nginx server will hehave exactly as the audio control use mp3 file from http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/_mp3/office_lobby.mp3.

Comment: Recompile nginx with —with-http_mp4_module can solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Similar problems happened for me too.

You may check the audio URL directly in the browser. If you meet "403 Forbidden" issue, that means your local mp3 has wrong permission.

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: In my case, the mp3 is played well, and when I type the URL in the browser I can download it successful. One of my colleague have resolved it by recompiling nginx with —with-http_mp4_module.